# antd DatePicker won't keep calendar open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, material-ui, antd

I am using antd DatePicker in my project, and somehow a simple `<DatePicker />`, no props, won't keep the calendar open when initially clicked. It opens for a brief second then closes before I can select a date or click outside. But somehow `<RangePicker />` has no such issue. Not sure if that matters, but the DatePicker is on a Material UI `<Drawer />` component, on top of an MUI `<Modal />`.

Does anyone have a theory of why that happens and how to resolve it?

Comment: Both `antd` `DatePicker` and `RangePicker` popups are closed when clicked outside. what do you really want to say? https://so-test-58966199.stackblitz.io/

Comment: @blueseal the problem is to keep open, before I select a date or click outside.

Comment: I don't think `antd` has `props` for that. can you just edit your question for better clarity?